# Simple auto-correct neural network not learning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm building a simple auto-correct neural network in Python. Here's the full code: [Code&Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i85z91a9zb9sn4c/Code.zip?dl=0)

Training data is just a list of words(included in link above) eg:

```
yellow
woods
four
```

Now, each word is assigned a unique number like:

```
yellow => 0.101
```

Then spelling mistakes are generated by replacing one char from input word with a random char. 
So about 4-5 spelling mistakes are generated for each word like:

```
yelbow => 0.101
ytllow => 0.101
```

Then I feed the list of spelling mistakes and their correct unique numbers to make it learn the pattern.

Sorry if it's bad explanation, please take a look at the code above.

Here is the training logic:

```
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((x_dim, hidden_dim)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((hidden_dim, x_dim)) - 1


for j in range(20000):
    err = 0
    input_arr, output_arr = shuffle(input_arr, output_arr)
    for i in range(len(input_arr)):
       X = input_arr[i]
       y = output_arr[i]

       l0 = X
       l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, syn0))
       l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, syn1))
       l2_err = y - l2

       l2_delta = l2_err * sigmoid(l2, deriv=True)
       l1_err = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
       l1_delta = l1_err * sigmoid(l1, deriv=True)

       syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta) * alpha
       syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta) * alpha
       err += np.mean(np.abs(l2_err))

    if(j % 1000) == 0:
       print str(j) + ", Error:" + str(err)
```

My issue is that it learns about 10-15 words properly with error reducing below 0.009 but for more words it fails to learn them and error remains around 0.4

[Full Code and Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i85z91a9zb9sn4c/Code.zip?dl=0)

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If your code works for a small number of words it may very well be that there is no code errors in your code but rather errors in the way you encoded your problem.

For one I don't think it's a good idea to encode words in float numbers. In that case you can have two different words which have very similar encoding: e.g. word:0.101 (yellow) and word:0.102 (four) (they differ only by 0.001). And this two words would have an encoding very different (relatively) from word:0.11 (golden) (they differ by 0.01, it's 10 times bigger). All those words are different and it would be a better idea to keep that in your encoding.

I think the good way to encode words in your problem would be to use integers from 0 to N-1, where N is your number of words. You can then use a softmax layer together with a cross entropy loss to train your network. One side benefit of using a categorical loss is that you will have a much more meaningful loss: the percentage of good guesses that your network makes which is much easier to interpret than your loss.

Overall problems can arise in many ways when training neural networks and it's hard to answer them easily if you don't have a specific questions regarding your code. Things you should consider to debug your code:

-try to train it without noise in the words. In that case your network should learn the identity, it should not be too hard and if it doesn't work it might be because there are errors in your code.

-try to vary the amount of noise

-you can have a look at the weights of you neural network. Do they indeed converge to some value or do they fluctuate randomly ?